# platform.linux_distribution() deprecated - what are the alternatives?

Tags: python, linux

As of Python 3.5 [`platform.linux_distribution()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/platform.html#platform.linux_distribution) is deprecated and it's planned to be removed from Python 3.7.

Is there anything I could uses instead of `platform.linux_distribution()`?

`platform.uname()` doesn't yield the information I need. I'm running the code in a Docker container and `platform.uname()` returns the details for the host machine, not the image.

In particular, I'm building a [portable Linux distribution](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) and I want to test it on the canonical CentOS 5.11 distribution. I'm looking for a simple way to identify the OS to identify/tag the build results.

Comment: The function is still present in Python 3.5 and 3.6. I do however get a different answer (on the same machine) compared to Python 3.4.

Comment: `uname` will return information on the Linux kernel not the distribution and the kernel is the very same for the host and the container (not the image).

Comment: Please read [Python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue1322) for details. You can try and parse `/etc/lsb-release` to get more accurate information, if available.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [Deprecated platform.linux_distribution() and platform.dist()](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37070), the `platform.linux_distribution()` will be removed from Python 3.7. It is indeed still present in Python 3.6. The recommended alternative is the [distro](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distro) package.

After installing the package, you can use the following code.

```py
import distro
distro.linux_distribution()
```

In newer versions of the *distro* package, `distro.linux_distribution()` has been deprecated. Instead, the package makes available `distro.id()`, `distro.version()`, and `distro.name()`.

Comment: To be precise more accurate replacement is `distro.linux_distribution(full_distribution_name=False)`

Comment: @msuchy That is not a like-for-like replacement for Python platform method `If full_distribution_name is true (default), the full distribution read from the OS is returned. `

Comment: distro.linux_distribution has also been deprecated https://github.com/python-distro/distro/pull/296

Answer (score -1):

Another option is `platform.uname()`:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.uname()
uname_result(system='Linux', node='lensman', release='4.19.84', version='#1-NixOS SMP Tue Nov 12 18:21:46 UTC 2019', machine='x86_64', processor='')
```