# Aws lambda function while trying to import wand module

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

This is the error I am getting when I am trying to run an AWS lambda function. The call it choking on is the import `wand.image import image`  I have the packages on the same level of the directory as the rest of the files. Im running windows and python 3.8

```
{
  "errorMessage": "module 'platform' has no attribute 'linux_distribution'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/event_handler.py\", line 6, in <module>\n    from wand.image import Image\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/wand/image.py\", line 18, in <module>\n    from . import assertions\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/wand/assertions.py\", line 125, in <module>\n    from .color import Color  # noqa: E402\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/wand/color.py\", line 10, in <module>\n    from .api import library\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/wand/api.py\", line 161, in <module>\n    distname, _, __ = platform.linux_distribution()\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can encourage other users to help you on your issue by providing a [minimal, reproducible and working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `platform.linux_distribution` is deprecated starting Python 3.7 so it would not be available in Python 3.8.

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554443/platform-linux-distribution-deprecated-what-are-the-alternatives)

The alternative is to use:

```
import distro
distro.linux_distribution()
```

Hope it helps!